# Save same Entry more than once with help of custom relations field

Tags: entry, custom-field

Is it possible to save the same Entry (red arrow) twice/more than once in one custom relations field?

"Test Playlist" is a entry in a channel.

Background:

I have set up a playlist, where an entry should be saved more than once.

[image: Save Entry in Playlist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you could use [a Matrix field](https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields) containing a Entries field.

Comment: thanks stephen. i forgot to mention, that users add entries via a frontend formular to theirs playlist.  and users should be able to erase entries as well.
are matrix fields still the way to go?

Comment: In terms of how you store the data, you don't really have any other choice, at least natively. You can structure the front-end form however you wish, as long as the data submitted to Craft is in the correct format. If you're unsure how Craft names Matrix fields (for example), just take a look at the source of a CP form.